# How do I fix a COM32 Error?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have recently downloaded Ubuntu and it is a great operating system, don't get me wrong, but I want Windows 7.

I saw that I can install it to a separate partition and I made the partition, but, when I go to install Windows 7 to the separate partition, I get an error that says something along the lines of "missing COM 32 file".

Is this Ubuntu's doing? Is it the way I'm going about things? I've tried re-formatting the USB I'm using but, it doesn't seem to work.